# Average Volume specific to a 1 Day Timeframe

Tags: pine-script

What I'm trying to achieve in Pine Script is a static average volume of the previous 3 and 30 days, that stays the same when using any timeframe chart.

I have code that currently works on the 1D resolution, but as soon as you change the resolution so does the calc.  Which I presume is due to square bracket call relates to the previous bar and not specified resolution?

I can't use the resolution call in the Study parameter and I've tried 2 ways but neither seems to work, so any help is welcome.

```
study("Average Volume Indicator", "AVI", overlay = false)

//  User Inputs
res = input("D", "Timeframe", input.resolution, group = "Volume Selection")
vlg = input(30, "Long Period", step = 1, group = "Volume Selection")
vsh = input(3, "Short Period", step = 1, group = "Volume Selection")

//  Calculations
// vol = volume[1] / 1000000
vol = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, volume, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)[1] / 1000000
vma_lg = sma(vol, vlg) == na ? vol : sma(vol, vlg)
vma_sh = sma(vol, vsh) == na ? vol : sma(vol, vsh)
vma_per = (vma_sh - vma_lg) / vma_lg * 100

avg_lg = 0.0 / vlg
for i = 0 to (vlg - 1)
    avg_lg := avg_lg + vol[i]
avg_lg := avg_lg / vlg

avg_sh = 0.0 / vsh
for i = 0 to (vsh - 1)
    avg_sh := avg_sh + vol[i]
avg_sh := avg_sh / vsh

vol_per = (avg_sh-avg_lg)/avg_lg * 100

table vol_tab = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 1, bgcolor=color.new(color.white,50))

table.cell(vol_tab, 1, 0, "VOL: " + tostring(vol_per, "0") + "%", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(vol_tab, 2, 0, "VMA: " + tostring(vma_per, "0") + "%", text_color = color.white)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear on what the bottom half of the script accomplishes, but here is the top half, which calculates the 2 volume averages and the percentage on the daily time frame. Best practice is to make the calculations first, then ask the higher time frame what is happening there, and security() does the rest. Please note that this security() variety is best practice for avoiding repainting and only uses confirmed data (previous close). If you want to change that, its up to you, but the method is the same.

```
//@version=4 
study("Average Volume Indicator", "AVI", overlay = false)

//  User Inputs
res = input("D", "Timeframe", input.resolution, group = "Volume Selection")
vlg = input(30, "Long Period", step = 1, group = "Volume Selection")
vsh = input(3, "Short Period", step = 1, group = "Volume Selection")

// functions 

    // non-repainting security function using last confrimed data only 
_NRP(tf, src) => 
    security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
 
//  Calculations

vma_lg   = sma(volume, vlg)
vma_sh   = sma(volume, vsh)
vma_per  = (vma_sh - vma_lg) / vma_lg * 100
    // render calcs from HTF. These are daily sma's and perc 
Dvma_lg  = _NRP(res,vma_lg) 
Dvma_sh  = _NRP(res,vma_sh)
Dvma_per = _NRP(res,vma_per)
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorgum, I'm still trying to get my head around Functions.

The bit at the bottom was just to display the figures in a table so that I could see if it was working as expected.

I take it in your function I need to substitute "tf" for "res"?  I guess your code is missing a declaration for "src" as it's giving me an error, should that be 'src = volume'?

Comment: the function is used at the bottom here for the 3 daily variables I made. Here we use the function and sub in values eg. _NRP(res,vma_lg) where your values are inserted. Above we just define the function so we can use it later multiple times

Comment: They all seem to be giving me the same figure as I was getting an Undeclared error for "src" in the Function and then addded "src =  volume"?

Comment: I apologize, I have edited the answer. Try this

Comment: I've just double checked and it only seems to work on either the specified timeframe or lower, it doesn't seem to work on higher timeframes?

Comment: correct. Security should only be used on a higher time frame than the present chart, never pulling up data from below